# UITableViewDataSource methods, default implementation

Tags: iphone

For a method like

```
(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

if I want to implement it for certain tableViews in my view, and not others, is there a way to return the default implementation?  TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just return super's implementation.

```
if (tableView == myTableView) {
  // create and return your custom header
}
else {
  return [super tableView:tableView viewForHeaderInSection:section];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because UITableViewDataSource is a protocol and has no super (default) method.  I think just returning nil is okay.