# UITableViewDataSource extension with default implementation

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift-protocols

**Question:** How to write a default implementation of `UITableViewDataSource` by extending it?

Swift supports default implementations in protocol extensions, and `UITableViewDataSource` is a protocol. So why doesn't the example below work?

I tried the example below, but the table stays blank. To be sure, I added breakpoints to the default implementations, and they aren't reached. I put `print` methods inside but they print nothing.

This extension would make usage of basic table views almost code-less, as they'd only need a collection of entities that conform to `TableItem`.

[This question with similar title is unrelated.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319389/uitableviewdatasource-methods-default-implementation)

Full example:

```
import UIKit

/// Conform to this protocol to be immediatelly usable in table views.
protocol TableItem {
    var textLabel: String? { get }
    var detailTextLabel: String? { get }
}

protocol BasicTableDataSource {

    associatedtype TableItemType: TableItem

    var tableItems: [TableItemType]? { get set }

    /// The table view will dequeue a cell with this identifier.
    /// Leave empty to use `cellStyle`.
    var cellIdentifier: String? { get set }

    /// If `cellIdentifier` is empty, the table view will use this cell style.
    /// Leave empty to use `UITableViewCellStyle.default`.
    var cellStyle: UITableViewCellStyle? { get set }

}

extension UITableViewDataSource where Self: BasicTableDataSource {

    func tableView(
        _ tableView: UITableView,
        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return tableItems?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(
        _ tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = cellIdentifier == nil
            ? UITableViewCell(
                style: cellStyle ?? .default,
                reuseIdentifier: nil)
            : tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: cellIdentifier!,
                for: indexPath)
        let tableItem = tableItems?[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableItem?.textLabel
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = tableItem?.detailTextLabel
        return cell
    }

}

class ProductsTableViewController: UITableViewController, BasicTableDataSource {

    var cellIdentifier: String?

    var cellStyle: UITableViewCellStyle? = .subtitle

    /// Product conforms to TableItem
    var tableItems: [Product]? = Sample.someProducts()

}
```

Comment: Do you try to call `.reloadData()` method in `viewDidLoad()` ?

Comment: I tried `.reloadData()` and it does nothing in this case

Comment: Where you set the `dataSource`? Something like this: `self.dataSource = self`

Comment: `UITableViewController` sets `dataSource` itself, it's not `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`extension UITableViewDataSource where Self: BasicTableDataSource`

With

`extension UITableViewDataSource`

Since `UITableViewDataSource` is not confirming to `BasicTableDataSource` protocol. So it will not extend `UITableViewDataSource`

[More about Protocol Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267)  Read about **Adding constraints to protocol extension.**

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** It's not possible to write a default implementation of `UITableViewDataSource` methods in an extension. This is a no-go.

Xcode now shows the errors:

> Non-'@objc' method 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'
>
> Non-'@objc' method 'tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)' does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

In February 2017, this issue [was officially closed](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3349?focusedCommentId=21826&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-21826) as "Won't Do" by one of the Swift Core Team members with the message below. [More history on this Stack Overflow topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487168/non-objc-method-does-not-satisfy-optional-requirement-of-objc-protocol)

> This is intentional: protocol extensions cannot introduce @objc entry points due to limitations of the Objective-C runtime. If you want to add @objc entry points to NSObject, extend NSObject.

Curious thing is that Xcode only started complaining when I replaced the inheritance from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`. This complains nothing:

```
class ProductsTableViewController: UITableViewController, BasicTableDataSource {

    var cellIdentifier: String?

    var cellStyle: UITableViewCellStyle? = .subtitle

    var tableItems: [Product]? = Sample.someProducts()

    // Table already exists in UITableViewController
}
```

...however this makes the extension start complaining:

```
class ProductsTableViewController: UIViewController, BasicTableDataSource, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var cellIdentifier: String?
    
    var cellStyle: UITableViewCellStyle? = .subtitle
    
    var tableItems: [Product]? = Sample.someProducts()

    // Adding table manually...
    
    var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

}
```